# ¿Como hago que dos funciones cambien su valor en PHP?

Tags: php, web, php7

Lo que busco es tener una variable $a y una variable $b, que pasado por una función me devuelva la variable $a el resultado de $b y la variable $b el resultado de $a.
El problema reside en que cuando cambio el valor de A por el de B no sé como hacer para que A vuelva a valer su propio valor para definir que B tiene que valer el valor de A.
Este sería el codigo:

```
<?php
function swap(&$a, &$b) {
    $a = $b;
    $b = $a;
    
}
$a = "One ";
$b = "Two";

echo $a; 
echo $b; 

swap($a, $b);

echo $a . $b;
```

Y el resultado sería One TwoTwo Two, cuando debería ser Two One en la parte final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que crear una variable auxiliar:

```
function swap(&$a, &$b) {
    $auxA = $a;
    $a = $b;
    $b = $auxA;
    
}
```

Comment: Si, efectivamente, muchisimas gracias